# How can I pass a parameter to a delegate callback method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, parameters, delegates

This seems really odd, so I doubt it's good practice but I'm working on an old app and I need to make some updates without totally redesigning the whole thing.

Currently, I have a UIButton which has an outlet as

```
- (IBAction) toggleBroadcast:(UIButton*) sender 
{
   // configure and start video capture
}
```

But I'm trying to implement remote configuration which makes a call to a php script with the device id and returns a (JSON parsed to) NSDictionary, which is loaded into a static config class.

Since networking requires asynchronous delegate methods and my 
`// configure and start video capture` code is dependent on the network-retrieved data, I have to make my toggleBroadcast function look like:

```
- (IBAction) toggleBroadcast:(UIButton*) sender 
    {
       // get identifier, fill request...
       // NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
                                                                      delegate:self];
    }
```

and the `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate method then calls my original `toggleBroadcast` code, which is now encapsulated separately so it can be called at the appropriate time.

BUT! I need that `sender`.

So how can I send `sender` as a parameter to my delegate method so I can send it to my new

`- (void) originalToggleBroadcastCode:(UIButton*) sender`?

Comment: Is all this code in the same controller?

Comment: Yes, everything is in the same view controller.

Comment: Not really sure why you need the sender. Is it needed to identify which NSURLConnection instance has just finished loading?

Comment: No, in my original non-remotely-configured `toggleBroadcast`, I have an `if (!sender.selected){// lots of UI setup}` that changes a few views when the play button is pressed.

Comment: How about just creating a property, and set it to sender in the toggleBroadcast method. Change the originalToggleBroadcastCode method to not have any arguments, and use the value of your property inside that method.

Comment: @rdelmar, that is what I plan to do if there is no simple way to do this, but I see that as slightly disorganized. Might resort to that though.

Comment: that is the simple way, anything else is more hacky than just storing it and using it later.

Comment: I agree that almost everything else is less straightforward, Wain. But Mike below has a pretty cool trick that isn't too far from what I imagined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the very nice [BlocksKit library](https://github.com/pandamonia/BlocksKit) which would then allow you to do:

```
- (IBAction) toggleBroadcast:(UIButton*) sender 
{
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request];

    connection.successBlock = ^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData){
         [self originalToggleBroadcastCode:sender];

    [connection start];
 };
```

Comment: That's pretty clever use of block scope.

Comment: Yeah, Blocks rule. And BlocksKit really helps cut down on some of those annoying delegate protocols.

Comment: Would your answer not work with native block support? Is the `successBlock` part of BlocksKit?

Comment: It's the BlocksKit library that gives you this and many more Blocks based goodies.

Answer (score 1):

to accomplish what you're asking, you could try creating an NSOperation subclass that accepts a UIView as an argument. This operation could perform the request, and then update the UIView when done. (be sure to do the UI update on the main thread). This seems like a strange design pattern though.

personally, I would have my view controller subscribe to notifications, and then send out a notification when the download is done. you can store info about the operation's success or failure in the userInfo dictionary that is stored in the NSNotification object, and respond appropriately. Again, be sure to send the completion notification on the main thread.